# What type of Connector is this?

Tags: connector, bnc

The connector on the left is a standard BNC, but could someone please tell me what the connector on the right is? 
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like an N type connector: -

[image]

Here's a picture of a BNC to N type converter (male and female versions): -

[image]

Taken from [here](https://www.futurlec.com/ConnNType.shtml)

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_connector) a wiki link

Comment: Thanks for the link to the converter, how did you know ;)

Comment: I use them now and then.

Comment: Any issues with power through the BNC? It will be passing upto 250W..?

Comment: I don't use them for power applications - just for connecting to an old spectrum analyser - according to the wiki link the N type OK for 5kW at 20MHz and 500W at 2GHz.

Comment: Do not use a BNC connector at 250W.....but it actually depends on your frequency. N-type will likely be able to handle whatever you can throw at it. (I'm assuming that, because you're asking, you don't have a 2 GHz 1KW CW amplifier lying around).

Answer (score 10):

It looks like an [N connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_connector) here is an image of a similiar looking [N Female Solder Chasis Mount Connector - RG58](http://www.showmecables.com/product/N-Female-Solder-Chasis-Mount-Connector-RG58.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an N type coaxial to me

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_connector